# Applying type classes until a fixpoint is reached in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, typeclass

tl;dr: Is there a way to automatically apply a type class recursively until no changes are performed anymore?

I have defined case classes that represent symbolic computations like this

```
trait SymbolicComputation

case class ConstZero() extends SymbolicComputation
case class Const[T](t: T) extends SymbolicComputation
case class Sum[S1, S2](s1: S1, s2: S2) extends SymbolicComputation
case class Product[F1, F2](f1: F1, f2: F2) extends SymbolicComputation
// ...
```

along with a type class to simplify trees of such computations

```
trait CanSimplify[-F] {
  type R
  def simplify(f: F): R
}


trait LowestPriorityCanSimplify {
  // Cannot simplify any further
  implicit def canSimplifyIdentity[F] = new CanSimplify[F] {
    type R = F
    def simplify(f: F) = f
  }
}

trait LowPriorityCanSimplify extends LowestPriorityCanSimplify {
  // Simplify summands
  implicit def canSimplifySummands[F1, F2](
    implicit canSimplifyFirst: CanSimplify[F1],
    canSimplifySecond: CanSimplify[F2]
  ) = new CanSimplify[Sum[F1, F2]] {
    type R = Sum[canSimplifyFirst.R, canSimplifySecond.R]

    def simplify(f: Sum[F1, F2]) = {
      Sum(
        canSimplifyFirst.simplify(f.s1),
        canSimplifySecond.simplify(f.s2)
      )
    }
  }
}

trait HighPriorityCanSimplify extends LowPriorityCanSimplify {
  // 0 + x = x
  implicit def canSimplifyZeroPlusF[F](
    implicit canSimplify: CanSimplify[F]
  ) =
    new CanSimplify[Sum[ConstZero, F]] {
      type R = canSimplify.R

      def simplify(f: Sum[ConstZero, F]) = {
        canSimplify.simplify(f.s2)
      }
    }

  // 0 * x = 0
  implicit def canSimplifyZeroTimesF[F] =
    new CanSimplify[Product[ConstZero, F]] {
      type R = ConstZero

      def simplify(f: Product[ConstZero, F]) = {
        ConstZero()
      }
    }
}

object CanSimplify extends HighPriorityCanSimplify {
  implicit class RichSimplifiable[F](f: F) {
    def simplify(implicit canSimplify: CanSimplify[F]) =
      canSimplify.simplify(f)
  }
}
```

Now when applying once, one iteration of simplification is performed correctly

```
import CanSimplify._

val s = Sum(ConstZero(), Sum(Product(ConstZero(), Const(2.0)), Const(1.0)))
// => s: Sum[ConstZero,Sum[Product[ConstZero,Const[Double]],Const[Double]]] = Sum(ConstZero(),Sum(Product(ConstZero(),Const(2.0)),Const(1.0)))
s.simplify
// => res0: Sum[ConstZero,Const[Double]] = Sum(ConstZero(),Const(1.0))
```

But actually, we need multiple (in this case 2) iterations to get to the simplest form

```
s.simplify.simplify
// => res1: Const[Double] = Const(1.0)
```

One idea that is not elegant but could work is to add a type-level integer (`Nat`) type parameter to CanSimplify and reduce that type parameter in every implicit application. Then one could start with a high number (the maximum number of simplifications that should be made) and stop only when the second parameter reaches `_0`.

Is there a nicer solution to this problem?

Comment: what's wrong if you apply a normal recursive algorithm? as far as i am concerned, your type appears to be a functor. if you want to make it compile time explicit, then you will need to encode layer to the type, otherwise how can compiler know? please clarify your question

Comment: Hi @HuStmpHrrr, what is a normal recursive algorithm on the type-level? I also don't understand the relation to functors and what kind of layer to encode in the type.
So much confusion :)

Comment: again, i don't see your question, so you should clarify. what youa re trying to do is extremely simple, i.e. evaluate an ast. there are 2k ways of doing this so it's very difficult for anyone to answer an over simplified question.